# Sonata Admin Dependent Select ajax returns empty value

Tags: ajax, symfony, sonata-admin

I have form with dependent selectBoxes.
I read tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.htmL

But in my representation ajax always return empty value
I use Sonata Admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You controller Action must implement method:

```
 if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return $this->render('MyBundle:Task:ajax-template.html.twig', [
           'form' => $view,
        ]);
    }
```

And template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```